# StrucutureMap RhinoMock Record/Playback, Example needed

Tags: .net, rhino-mocks, structuremap, unity-container, mocking

I'm looking for some examples on how to do the following Mock Tests using StructureMap or Unity with NUnit.

I have the following code structure

```
public interface IDAL
{
    List<Model> Method1(int id);
}

public class DAL : IDAL
{
   public List<Model> Method1(int id)
   {
        List<Model> retval = new List<Model>();
        DbCommand cmd = GetStoredProcCommand("Model_Method1");
        using (IDataReader dr = DB.ExecuteReader(cmd))
        {
            LoadEntityBaseList(retval, dr, PopulateDomain);//populate list based on reader
        }
        return retval;
   }
}

public class Manager
{
   private readonly IDAL m_DAL;
   public Manager()       
   {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.ForRequestedType<IDAL>());
        m_DAL = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IDAL>();

   }

   public List<Domain> Method1(int id)
   {
        return m_DAL.Method1(id);

   }
}

[TestFixture]
public class ManagerTests
    [Test]
    public void Method1_Calls_DAL()
    {

        var list = new List<Model>();
        using (m_mock.Record())
        {
            Expect.Call(_dal.Method1(1)).IgnoreArguments().Return(list);
        }
        using (m_mock.Playback())
        {
            Manager manager = new Manager();
            var actual = manager.Method1(1);
            Assert.That(actual, Is.Not.Null);
        }
    }
}
```

If I do include the StructureMap configuration It ignores the Mock and Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.VerifyAll() throws an exception.

If I don't include the structureMap configuration I get No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily MyObject.IDAL.

Can someone point me in the right direction on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectFactory.Initialize should only be called once during the lifetime of your application, so it does not make sense to call it from a class constructor.

Put the ObjectFactory.Initialize() method somewhere in the beginning of your program (Main() or Application_Start() for the web) then change Manager so that it takes an IDAL as a constructor argument.

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(...)
var manager = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<Manager>();

public class Manager {
 public Manager(IDAL dal){
  m_DAL = dal;
 }
 ...
}
```

Then in your unit test, you do not use StructureMap at all - you just pass in a mocked IDAL to Manager.

```
using (m_mock.Playback()) {
 Manager manager = new Manager(m_mock);
```

Comment: Yes that will work but,
I'm trying to avoid special casing the constructor just for mock testing

Comment: That isn't a special case. That is how you should design your classes when working with an IOC tool like StructureMap.